# A stranger's email has ended up as a saved username in my Google Account. How can this happen?

Tags: security, passwords, google-accounts

I'm really starting to question google's Password manager. I have two very strange cases here:

(Case 1. In Chrome, my brother found a username and password to a local newspaper in his Google account.  Using Facebook, he was able to find the person, and it was an older person he had never heard of or seen.)

Case 2. Today I was logging on to my Bank app on my Android phone, and Google showed two saved accounts. My own email, and some stranger's email I have never seen before. The email address is not random - it looks like firstnamelastname@gmail.com, where the name looks to be from the same country as me.

[image: Screenshot from Google Password manager]

One thing I found peculiar is that as shown on the screenshot, the first account shows an icon for both web and app.
While the second one does not show the app icon. I assume that means it has only been logged on through the web browser? I was not even aware that was possible, as the bank is App only, it's not possible to access the bank account through browser.

Let's first get the obvious causes out of the way:

1. I know 100% sure, that I never let anyone use my phone. It's never left my body. Any other devices I own are permanently in my house, where I have never had any strangers.
2. I have never sold or given any of my old phones/computers away.
3. The bank in question is not very well known. So even if someone had my phone, it would be incredibly random that they tried to sign in to the same bank as me.
4. In my Google account, there's no strange sign ins. I can only see sign ins from my own devices.
5. The username is saved with *my own password* (an old one). That makes no sense. If someone had my password, why would they log on with someone else's email?

Considering this, **does anyone have any suggestion as to how a stranger's email username could have found it's way to my stored passwords?**
I'll just mention that I'm a programmer, so I'm not clueless about technology.

My hottest take right now is that it must have been caused by a bug in the bank login form: When I entered the wrong password, a bug caused it to load a different customer's email as the username, so when I entered password again, it saved that to Google password manager?

Comment: Your guess isn't a bad one. I'd accept some random small bank having problems with their auth systems than Google. But, how is your Google account security? Do you have MFA set up on it and a strong and unique password?

Comment: I did not use MFA until today. But I think we can rule out that my Google Account has been compromised. The username in question probably has been saved there for a while, I just randomly noticed today. There's been no unusal activity on my Google Account, no unusual sign ins, and no emails asking if it was me who signed in.
The bank in question also always send email when sign on, and there's no unkown transactions.

Comment: Any password manager can be a point of failure. See https://password-managers.bestreviews.net/faq/which-password-managers-have-been-hacked/ for some examples. A cloud-based manager provides hackers a single point to attack that can give access to millions of passwords, a prime target. Was it an accident, similar to Google Drive losing user data? https://www.spiceworks.com/tech/data-management/news/google-drive-loses-user-data/